# How to position a Bootstrap btn-group at the bottom of a page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-push-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-4">
        <form onsubmit="return false">
            ...
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-push-1 col-sm-6 buttons text-center">
        <div class="btn-group">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I have a bootstrap row where a form takes 4 columns (tablet or larger screen) and a button group takes up 6 columns of the row. The button group automatically comes at the top of the right side of the row and I want it to be at the bottom of the right side of the row. I tried the following CSS code (where 'buttons' is the parent div of the button group), but it didn't work:

```
.buttons{
    position: absolute;
}
.btn-group{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If its in bootstrap wouldnt you change one of these classes `col-sm-6` so that is spans a full column width - https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: A working JSFiddle or something alike would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give the *btn-group*:

```
.btn-group{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

and be sure that the parent *div.buttons* has a:

```
.buttons{
    position: relative;
}
```

Give also the parent *.row*:

```
.row{
  display:flex;
}
```

Comment: Got a working fiddle? I think this approach won't work because .buttons doesn't have a height associated with it.

Comment: Hmmm are you sure bootstrap keeps working properly with .row display:flex;? I recall some trouble with that on a site I was working on. If it works, great, but better be careful with this.

Comment: Just add a spot change to that parent, otherwise we have to change approach like placing the btn-group into the parent. I've just updated the [pen](http://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/EywzRy) .

Comment: Thanks mate, this worked. Giving the parent row the display value of flex did the work.

Comment: @АбдулахХамзиќ You're welcome! Glad it helped you! :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be the other way around:

**.buttons** (the container) needs to have **relative** position;

**.btn-group** (the inner div) needs to have **absolute** position.

Also, make sure the container has the correct **hight**.

By the way, another technique to position an inner div in the proper place (bottom in your example) of an outer div, is using CSS' **vertical-align** property (thought additional changes would be needed, google it).

Comment: This is not correct because this techniques does not suit for forms actually we don't need to consider height of form or section...if OP want to add another fields in the feature he need to change height every time for this section.